Editing block to update/remove menu items
I am new to Drupal and I'm trying to fix items on a website, which have several blocks containing menu items. I don't want to delete the blocks, I just want to edit them to remove/update the menu items listed, as well as delete a block menu item labeled "separator." When I am in administrator mode and hover my cursor around the block, my only options are to configure or delete, and the configure doesn't let me access it in editing mode.
Any suggestions you might have in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

The edit/delete links you are seeing are probably links for the block the menu is embedded in, not links for the menu itself.
If the menu is built as a Drupal menu - usually they are, but everyone has built a hacky Drupal site in their career - you can find the menu at Admin -> Structure -> Menus. There will be a number of menus in there, you'll need to go through them to identify which menu you specifically want to make changes to.
Note that Drupal can be configured with sidebar menus that are actually subsets of a larger menu, with the subset based on the current page context. So you may have to dig deeper into the hierarchy than you may be thinking on some of these menus. Some menus will be really, really long.
When searching for a menu item that I don't know what menu it's in, I'll go to each menu page, and do browser search in the page for the menu item. If you find it, consider that a menu item with the same name and path can exist in multiple menus, so it can sometimes be worth making sure you check EVERY menu, so that you aren't making changes to a same-named item in a different menu, and being confused as to why it's not changed on the front end. (May or may not be based on a true story)
